# MVEL 'in' operator not working for collections in java

Tags: java, mvel

I'm trying to use  MVEL 'in' operator in my code to evaluate an expression

```
List<String> countriesAvailable = new ArrayList<String>();
countriesAvailable.add("Australia");
countriesAvailable.add("France");
List<String> countriesVisited = new ArrayList<String>();
countriesVisited.add("Austria");
countriesVisited.add("France");
Map<String, List<String>> vars = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
vars.put("countriesAvailable", countriesAvailable);
vars.put("countriesVisited", countriesVisited);
Boolean s = (Boolean) MVEL.eval("countriesVisited in countriesAvailable", vars);
System.out.println(s);
```

Gives Error: syntax error or incompatible types

Comment: My guess is it expects countriesVisited to be a String type not a List<String> type. It probably looks to see if countriesAvailable contains any of countriesVisited where countriesVisited is expected to be a string.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell I tried making countriesVisited as String but even that is giving same error. Any alternative better way to check 'containsAny' for 2 lists using MVEL ?

Comment: I posted an answer but just noticed you want a containsAny instead of a containsAll. Do you want to see if any of the countries in countriesVisited are in countriesAvailable? Or are you trying to make sure the ones that visited are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution. You need to use `containsAll`

Also note that you misspelled Australia in the second list. I'm not sure if that was on purpose to check the evaluation.

```
    List<String> countriesAvailable = new ArrayList<String>();
    countriesAvailable.add("Australia");
    countriesAvailable.add("France");

    List<String> countriesVisited = new ArrayList<String>();
    countriesVisited.add("Austria");
    countriesVisited.add("France");

    Map<String, List<String>> vars = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    vars.put("countriesAvailable", countriesAvailable);
    vars.put("countriesVisited", countriesVisited);

    Boolean s = (Boolean) MVEL.eval(
            "countriesAvailable.containsAll(countriesVisited)", vars);

    System.out.println("Result = " + s);
```

`Result = false`

You can also use the `java.util.Collections` to perform a disjoint. And take the negative of that.

```
Boolean s = 
   (Boolean) MVEL.eval(
         "!java.util.Collections.disjoint(countriesAvailable,countriesVisited)",
         vars);
```

`Result = true`

Comment: @user401445 Ok that makes sense. At any rate the answer I posted will work. The second line will return true if any of the visited is in available.

Comment: The only use of the `in` operator I can find is in projection. http://mvel.codehaus.org/Projections+and+Folds Which is not what you need.